# ymodem vi for labview

Tags: stm32, labview

is there an implementation for ymodem protocol in labview. I want to make a binary file transfer from pc to stm32 using ymodem protocol and using labview.
I have searched a lot but didn't find any implementation of ymodem for labview

Comment: Can you give more information? What is the application? What is the device you are trying to communicate?

Comment: i want to transfer a binary file using labview to stm32 so my bootloader supports ymodem file transfer using serial port. so is there any vi for labview that transmits a file using ymodem directly over serial port.

Comment: There seem to be command-line file transfer programs available for Windows and other OSes that can send using Ymodem, so I would look for one of those and call it with System Exec. As it stands your question is likely to be closed as not a programming question - software recommendations are off-topic for Stack Exchange.

Comment: i know there are command-line file transfer programs for windows. That is not the issue my concern is to do the same file transfer using labview itself. i want to make a vi that uses visa to transfer a file using ymodem protocol using serial in labview.

Comment: Just call windows command line within the labview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labview has serial read/write capability.  Research the protocol and write your own vi to do the job.

Comment: Yup. I am on it ..! Anyways thanks for the rply guys.!